# How to fix the issue of "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed" without using DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: swiftui

Following is the complete code with an Xcode warning

[image]

We can fix this by uncommenting these 3 lines

```swift
//        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
//            viewModel.didUpdateTextView(uiView)
//        }
```

However, is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

```swift
import SwiftUI

@MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count: Int = 0

    func didUpdateTextView(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.count = textField.text?.count ?? 0
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        UIKitTextField(text: $text)
    }
}

public struct UIKitTextField: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            UIKitTextFieldRepresentable(viewModel: viewModel, text: $text)
            Text("Word count: \(viewModel.count)")
        }
        
    }
}


struct UIKitTextFieldRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    @Binding var text: String
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        viewModel.didUpdateTextView(uiView)
//        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
//            viewModel.didUpdateTextView(uiView)
//        }
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: UIKitTextFieldRepresentable
        init(_ textField: UIKitTextFieldRepresentable) {
            self.parent = textField
        }
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simplify your code a little, such as:

```
 @MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var count: Int = 0
 }
```

and in your `func updateUIView(...)`, as an alternative, use

```
 Task {
     viewModel.count = text.count
 }
```

which is similar to using:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     viewModel.count = text.count
 }
```

Note, you can use the same approach if you decide to use a simple `@State private var count: Int = 0` to pass to the`UIKitTextFieldRepresentable` and using a `@Binding var count: Int`

Another alternative is to use SwiftUI `TextField`, such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count = 0
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text).border(.red)
            .onChange(of: text) {
                count = text.count
            }
        Text("Word count: \(count)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In SwiftUI you should use the `View` structs for your view data not a class or a `StateObject` (that's designed for something else).

The best way to achieve what you are trying is `State` for the text and a computed var for the count. This way you are using SwiftUI's dependency tracking correctly. When body reads the computed count it has to call the text State getter which configures a dependency so it will call body again whenever text State is set. You would lose this functionality with classes and end up with consistency bugs.